# Connectedness between subsets

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I know a theorem:

> If in a topological space $(X,\tau)$  we have: $S\subset T\subset \overline{S}$ and $S$ is connected set then also $T$ is connected. In particular, the closure of a connected space is connected.

I have two question:

1. Is there a similar claim: we have $A\subset B\subset C$ and $A,C$ are connected, then $B$ is connected?
2. $S$ is connected $\Rightarrow$ $\overline{S}$ is connected, but $\Leftarrow$ is not truth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, that's far too weak! Take $A=\{0\}$ and $C=\mathbb R$. Both are connected, but obviously there are subsets like $B=(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ which aren't.
2. Yes, consider $S=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ in $\mathbb R$. This is obviously disconnected, but its closure is $[0,2]$, which is connected.

Comment: Do you mean $S=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ ? The notation $\{{0,1\}}$ denotes a set consisting of two elements.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Oops yes...I'm not sure what I was thinking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(1) is obviously false. For example, consider $X=\mathbb{R}$, equipped
with the usual topology. Let $A=\emptyset$, $B=(-2,-1)\cup(1,2)$,
and $C=\mathbb{R}$. Clearly $A$ and $C$ are connected, $A\subseteq B\subseteq C$
but $B$ is not connected.

Answer (score 1):

For 1.: no, the similar claim doesn't hold: take for instance the segment $A = [-1/2, 1/2] \times \{ 0 \}$ inside the plane. Let $B = B((0,0), 1) \cup B((2,2),1)$, $B(x,r)$ being the ball of center $x$ and radius $r$. Take $C$ any connected set which contains $B$ (for example $\mathbb R^2$ itself) and you have a counterexample.

For 2.: The "$\Leftarrow$" is indeed not true: $\overline {\mathbb Q} = \mathbb R$, so $\overline {\mathbb Q}$ is connected. But $\mathbb Q$ is not connected: the sets $A = (-\infty, \sqrt 2)$, $B = (\sqrt 2,\infty)$ disconnect it.

Answer (score 1):

We assume the following fact without proof: Let $X$ be a topological
space. Then the following conditions are equivalent:

(a) $X$ is connected.

(b) For any continuous function $f:X\rightarrow\{0,1\},$ $f$ is
a constant function.

---

We go back to your question. Let $f:T\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ be an arbitrary
continuous function. We go to show that $f$ is a constant function.
Let $g=f|_{S}$, the restriction of $f$ on $S$. Clearly $g:S\rightarrow\{0,1\}$
is also continuous. By the above fact, $g$ is a constant function.
Without loss of generality, we assume that $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in S$.
Let $x\in T$ be arbitrary. Since $x\in\bar{S}$, there exists a net
$(x_{\alpha})$ in $S$ such that $x_{\alpha}\rightarrow x$. By continuity
of $f$, we have that $f(x_{\alpha})\rightarrow f(x).$ However, $f(x_{\alpha})=g(x_{\alpha})=0$
for each $\alpha$, so $f(x)=0.$ This shows that $f$ is a constant
function.

Comment: Sorry... It seems that you are not asking for the proof of that theorem...